# Integer returned as sum of digits?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

Here is what I'm supposed to write:

- a function, countDigits, which will take an integer as a parameter and return the sum of its digits (you must use a for loop).  For instance, the number 123 would return 6 (1 + 2 + 3)
- a main function which will count numbers starting at one, and ending when the total digits (for all the numbers) exceeds 1,000,000.  So, if you want the total digits for the number 5, you would add:

  - 1 = 1
  - 2 = 2  + 1
  - 3 = 3 + 3
  - 4 = 6 + 4
  - 5 = 10 + 5, so 15 would be the total digit count.
- your program will print both the number and the digit count before it exceeds 1,000,000.  This is easiest with a while loop.

I've written the code for the function countDigits, which is:

```
def countDigits():
    value=int(input('Enter Integer: '))
    str_num= str(value)
    total = 0
    for ch in str_num:
        total += int(ch)
    print(total)
```

However, I'm stuck as to how to write the main function. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

Here is my revised countDigits function:

```
def countDigits(value):
    str_num= str(value)
    total = 0
    for ch in str_num:
        total += int(ch)
    print(total)
```

Comment: Your `countDigits` function is not right: "countDigits, which will take an integer as a **parameter** and **return** the sum of its digits". You are getting user input and printing.

Comment: Once you fix `countDigits`, it should become obvious how to write the main function, assuming you know how to call functions with arguments and assign the return value to a variable.

Comment: *"Can anyone point me in the right direction?"* is **not** an appropriate question for SO. Try something, test it, read and understand that outputs or errors it gives and try to improve it.

Comment: This is one of those INCREDIBLY rare circumstances where I wish `reduce` was still in Python..........

Comment: @AdamSmith it's still in `functools`

Comment: @kjc Your revised function is better, but still needs to `return` instead of `print`. Then you can call it from `main`, in a `while` loop, something like @Adam Smith's answer.

Answer (score 2):

a one-liner:

```
factorial_digit_sum = lambda x: sum( sum(map(int, str(a))) for a in range(1,x+1) )
```

If you EVER write real code like this, Guido will hunt you down. Was kind of a fun brain teaser to golf, though.

For a real answer:

```
def countDigits(number):
    return sum(map(int, str(number)))

def main():
    total = 0
    count = 1
    while total <= 1000000:
        total += countDigits(count)
    total -= countDigits(count) # you want the number BEFORE it hits 1000000
    print("Summing the digits of {}! yields {}".format(count, total))

main()
```

The problem in your code is that your `countDigits` function requests user input. You should change that to accepting the integer as a parameter. It also `print`s the result instead of `return`ing it.

Comment: @Kjc21793 yes for obvious homework assignments I tend to either golf for the pleasure of it (like I did here) or throw in some bits of syntax that I'm 99% sure you won't have learned yet. This forces you to either rewrite the code, with an idea of how it's SUPPOSED to come together, or be an obvious plagiarist and face academic sanctions.

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I want to know why it is the answer instead of just copy-pasting, otherwise it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Kjc21793 however I did answer in something APPROACHING a worthwhile format. This still contains things you're unlikely to have been taught (`map`, `str.format`) so if you copy verbatim, be prepared to receive a stern talking to :P

Answer (score 1):

As @Blorgbeard mentioned in the comments, change `countDigits` to accept an integer as input. Also, return the total from it.

In the main function, read input, call `countDigits` and add them in a while loop until the total is greater than 1,000,000

```
def countDigits(value):
    str_num= str(value)
    total = 0
    for ch in str_num:
        total += int(ch)
    return total

grandTotal = 0
while ( grandTotal < 1000000 ):
  value=int(input('Enter Integer: '))
  grandTotal += countDigits(value)
```